# C++: Possibility to assign multiple Interfaces

Tags: c++, interface, styles

I ran into a strange situation, and I wonder if there is a better way to implement this. I would be very thankful for suggestions.
It comes down to this simple core problem:

```
  //Interface I1 and I2 shall not be combined, since that makes logically no sense
class I1 {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class I2 {
public:
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};

//Some classes implements both interfaces I1 and I2 (some others don't, but that's not relevant here)
class A : public I1, public I2 {
public:
  void foo() override {};
  void bar() override {};
};

class B : public I1, public I2 {
public:
  void foo() override {};
  void bar() override {};
};

//Since there is no logically meaningful parent for I1 and I2, I have to do something like this,
//to access both interfaces of class A and B
struct pair_t {
  I1& accessViaI1;
  I2& accessViaI2;
};

A a;
B b;

std::deque<pair_t> items;

items.push_back({ a, a });
items.push_back({ b, b });
```

The code is working and because there are references used for the deque, the performance should be not too bad. But at least the last lines look very strange for me. Does anyone have an idea how to code this? Or maybe an suggestion for the general structure?
The main problem is, I1 and I2 are logically totally separated and independent. But if an objects implements both, I need them both.
Same as for class A and B, it makes no sense to combine them together (neither via inheritance nor as composition)

I can use C++11 and boost.
Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what do you consider "strange"?

Comment: What's exactly strange for you? The fact that you need to call the same object two times on push_back? You may define copy/init operations with specializations for A and B on pair_t, so you call the object only once on push_back. But behind the scenes it will be doing exactly this.

Comment: It's exactly that. Since I am not the only one to use this functionality in future, this might lead to confusion. Maybe it is a personal thing, because I have long time programmed in very low performance environment, but passing the same parameter twice should be unnecessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve

```
items.push_back({ a, a });
items.push_back({ b, b });
```

into

```
items.push_back({ a });
items.push_back({ b });
```

You might add constructors to your `pair_t`

```
struct pair_t {
  pair_t(I1& accessViaI1, I2& accessViaI2) :
      accessViaI1(accessViaI1),
      accessViaI2(accessViaI2)
  {}

  template <typename T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<I1, T>::value
                                && std::is_base_of<I2, T>::value, int>::type = 0>
  pair_t(T& t): pair_t(t, t) {}

  I1& accessViaI1;
  I2& accessViaI2;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rWsvqobP5)

Comment: Looks very promising for me, because it is the easiest way for the user of my library, so I can hide the push_back({a, a}). But unfortunately I am not familiar with enable_if. I tried to google, but what does the "=0" at the end does? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is a way to do [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Syntax is a bit ugly. constraint (of C++20) has better syntax: `template <typename T> requires(std::is_base_of<I1, T>::value && std::is_base_of<I2, T>::value) pair_t(T& t): pair_t(t, t) {}`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will go further with this solution. Although SFINAE syntax is really hard for me to understand, this seems for me the easiest way for the user, who has not to deal with the enable_if, but only with the queue handling. In addition, this is totally type safe and does not affect the logical structure of my interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

try `variant` instead:

```
using variant = std::variant<A, B>;
variant a = A();
variant b = B();
std::deque<variant> items;
items.push_back(a);
items.push_back(b);
```

`variant` is valid since c++17, but boost may has this feature as well.

Comment: By the way, you can also use a pointer to A or B. Such as a void pointer, and reinterprint it when used.